# duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 qt

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I started with Qt and now I have got this error:

```
duplicate symbol _t in:
    main.o
    handler.o
duplicate symbol _mp in:
    main.o
    handler.o
duplicate symbol _l in:
    main.o
    handler.o 
duplicate symbol _ti in:
    main.o
    handler.o 
ld: 4 
duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "handler.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QFile *file = new QFile(":/xml/example.tmx");

    QXmlSimpleReader xmlReader;
    QXmlInputSource *source = new QXmlInputSource(file);

    Handler *handler = new Handler;
    xmlReader.setContentHandler(handler);
    xmlReader.setErrorHandler(handler);

    bool ok = xmlReader.parse(source);
    if (!ok)
        std::cout << "Parsing failed." << std::endl;
    else {
        QStringList names = handler->names();
        QStringList attributes = handler->attributes();
        QStringList attributeName = handler->attributeName();
        QList<int> indentations = handler->indentations();
        QList<int> anzahl = handler->anzahl();
        int items = names.count();

        int durchgang = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < items; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < indentations[i]; ++j){
                std::cout << " ";
            }
            std::cout << names[i].toLocal8Bit().constData() << " " ;
            //weitere attribute printen(so viele wie vorhanden

            for(int y = 0; y < anzahl[i] ; y++){
                std::cout << attributeName[durchgang].toLocal8Bit().constData() << " = "<< attributes[durchgang].toLocal8Bit().constData() << "   ";
                durchgang++;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

        imageloader il;
        QStringList sources;
        for(int x = 0; x < mp.tilesets.length();x++){
            sources.append(mp.tilesets[x].source);
        }
        QList <QImage> images;
       images = il.Loadtilesets(mp.tilesets.length(),sources);
    }
    std::cout << "Beendet"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

handler.cpp:

```
#include "handler.h"

/*!
    Reset the state of the handler to ensure that new documents are
    read correctly.

    We return true to indicate that parsing should continue.
*/

bool Handler::startDocument()
{
    elementName.clear();
    elementAttributes.clear();
    elementIndentation.clear();
    elementAnzahl.clear();
    elementAttributeName.clear();
    indentationLevel = 0;

    return true;
}

/*!
    Process each starting element in the XML document.

    Append the element name to the list of elements found; add its
    corresponding indentation level to the list of indentation levels.

    Increase the level of indentation by one column.

    We return true to indicate that parsing should continue.
*/

bool Handler::startElement(const QString &, const QString &,
    const QString & qName, const QXmlAttributes & atts)
{
    elementName.append(qName);
    int anzahl = 0;

    for(int index = 0; index < atts.length();index++){
        int d = index;
        if(qName == "map"){//alle attribute von map
            if(atts.qName(index) == "width"){
                mp.width = atts.value(index).toInt();
                index ++;
            }
            if(atts.qName(index)== "height"){
                mp.height = atts.value(index).toInt();
                index++;
            }
        }

        if(qName == "tileset"){
        tileset t;

            if(atts.qName(index)=="firstgid"){
                t.firstgid = atts.value(index).toInt();
                index++;
            }
            if(atts.qName(index)=="name"){
                t.name = atts.value(index);
                index ++;
            }
            if(atts.qName(index)=="tilewidth"){
                t.tilewidth = atts.value(index).toInt();
                index++;
            }
            if(atts.qName(index)=="tileheight"){
                t.tileheight = atts.value(index).toInt();
                index++;
            }
            if(atts.qName(index)=="tilecount"){
                t.tilecount = atts.value(index).toInt();
                index++;
            }
            if(atts.qName(index)=="columns"){
                t.columns = atts.value(index).toInt();
                index++;
            }
        }
        if(qName == "image"){//!muss noch ein try catch block einbauen fals ein image nicht hinter einem tileset ist
            if(atts.qName(index) == "source"){
                t.source = atts.qName(index);
                mp.tilesets.append(t);
            }
        }
        if(qName =="layer"){
            if(atts.qName(index)=="name"){
                l.name = atts.qName(index);
                index++;
            }
            if(atts.qName(index)=="width"){
                l.width = atts.qName(index).toInt();
                index++;
            }
            if(atts.qName(index)=="height"){
                l.height= atts.qName(index).toInt();
                index++;
            }
        }
        if(qName == "data"){
            for(int x = 0; x< l.height*l.width; x++){
                if(atts.qName(index)=="gid"){
                    ti.gid = atts.value(index).toInt();
                    l.tiles.append(ti);
                    index++;
                }

            }
            mp.layers.append(l);
        }

        index = d;//für das auslesen und couten
        elementAttributes.append(atts.value(index));
        elementAttributeName.append(atts.qName(index));
        anzahl = index+1;
    }

    elementAnzahl.append(anzahl);

    elementIndentation.append(indentationLevel);
    indentationLevel += 1;

    return true;
}
/*!
    Process each ending element in the XML document.

    Decrease the level of indentation by one column.

    We return true to indicate that parsing should continue.
*/

bool Handler::endElement(const QString &, const QString &,
    const QString &)
{
    indentationLevel -= 1;
    return true;
}

/*!
    Report a fatal parsing error, and return false to indicate to the reader
    that parsing should stop.
*/

bool Handler::fatalError (const QXmlParseException & exception)
{
    qWarning() << QString("Fatal error on line %1, column %2: %3").arg(
        exception.lineNumber()).arg(exception.columnNumber()).arg(
        exception.message());

    return false;
}

/*!
    Return the list of element names found.
*/

QStringList& Handler::names ()
{
    return elementName;
}

QList<int>& Handler::indentations ()
{
    return elementIndentation;
}
QStringList& Handler::attributes ()
{
    return elementAttributes;
}
QList<int>& Handler::anzahl (){
    return elementAnzahl;
}
QStringList& Handler::attributeName (){
    return elementAttributeName;
}
```

handler.h:

```
#ifndef HANDLER_H
#define HANDLER_H

#include <qxml.h>
#include "structs.h"
#include "imageloader.h"
#include <qfile.h>
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>

class Handler : public QXmlDefaultHandler
{
public:
    bool startDocument();
    bool startElement(const QString &, const QString &, const QString &qName,
                       const QXmlAttributes &atts);
    bool endElement(const QString &, const QString &, const QString &);

    bool fatalError(const QXmlParseException &exception);
    QStringList& attributes();
    QStringList& names();
    QStringList& attributeName();
    QList<int>& anzahl();
    QList<int>& indentations();

private:
    int indentationLevel;
    QStringList elementName;
    QStringList elementAttributes;
    QStringList elementAttributeName;
    QList<int> elementAnzahl;
    QList<int> elementIndentation;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Some header included in both .cpp files defines variables, or functions that are not `inline`. They ought to match the names `ti` and `mp`. Something in `"structs.h"` perhaps?.

Comment: Minimize your code please, don't dump everything you got.

Comment: Sorry I didnt Know that.

Comment: Have you seen the help centre, taken the tour, and read about how to create a [mcve]?  In particular, note the "minimal" there.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have global variables *defined* in .h files, which won't work if the .h file is included in many .cpp files (which is basically the purpose of .h file, so...).

To do it properly, you should have something like this *declaration* in a .h file:

```
extern int t;
```

And then in *one* .cpp file, at top level (not inside a function) you should have the actual *definition*:

```
int t;
```

The first line just tells *compiler* that there is `int t` global variable somewhere, so it just uses it and trusts linker to find it. Then when *linker* looks for that symbol, and it must find exactly one of them, or it will complain either about duplicate symbols, or about not finding a symbol.

---

I won't get more deep into this (hows or whys), but this is C++ *and* Qt, so you should basically avoid global variables like this almost completely (they're bad enough in C, but there you have less alternatives). Since you're learning, you don't need to stress about it, just use them now, but keep in mind that you should learn ways to do things so that you don't need them.

Comment: Thank you very much